# Has Hulk ever been defeated by a normal person with limited weaponry?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I am a fan of the Marvel universe but don't follow much of its comics. So please spare my ignorance.

Just to elaborate what I am asking, let's take Hawkeye as our subject. Hawkeye doesn't have super powers. He has been trained to achieve an extreme level of accuracy, timing and precision. He relies on weapons like bow and arrow, guns and melee weapons. These weapons have limited power, range and ammunition. These weapons can be upgraded to amplify the effects, but still they won't match power of Iron Man's weapons.

Now what I want to know is has Hawkeye, or any other character from the Marvel universe without super powers, a normal human, defeated Hulk?

Conditions:

1. Hulk must not be in Bruce Banner form.
2. Characters like Iron Man and Falcon don’t count. Though they are normal humans, they have extremely high-tech weaponry to assist them. (Yes, Hawkeye too has sophisticated/modified arrows. But they still have limitations and Hawkeye has to rely on raw skills to use them.)
3. Specified character was not under the influence of power-enhancing materials, power-altering commands, enchantments or any other sort of power enhancing mechanism.
4. Hulk was not be under any material, power altering command, enchantment or any other sort of mechanism that suppresses his powers.
5. Specified character must have fought alone without any assistance. (Examples: a) Thor has already beaten shit out of Hulk and then Hawkeye comes to deliver the last shot; b) while in a fight, Thor comes in to distract Hulk so that Hawkeye can attack from behind.)
6. Specified character received assistance from another character who didn't have a superpower, but again didn't have extremely awesome weapons to assist. (Example: Black Widow).
7. Hulk was unaware of specified character's presence. Specified character took Hulk by surprise.
8. Use of tranquilizers or similar weapons which can put Hulk to sleep or render him unconscious, paralyzed or unable to act are not considered.
9. Hulk must not have run away from the fight because his opponent is not of his match.
10. (w.r.t. point no. 6) An army of normal humans will not be considered. Neither will be the situation where a single human calls in a S.H.I.E.L.D.-like agency for assistance be considered.
11. Bruce Banner's love interest or S.O. was not brought between the fighters to get Hulk to calm down.

Has any such event occurred ever in the Marvel universe where a normal human has defeated Hulk?

And aside from just Hulk being defeated by a normal human, any other incident where a powerful superhero/villain like Groot, Thanos or Ultron have been defeated by a normal human would be interesting.

Comment: If you guys want a long discussion in this,  please take it to [chat].

Comment: Given that BB tried to shoot himself (as mentioned in Avengers 1), and "the other guys just spat the bullet out", I'm assuming Muggle weapons are probably quite ineffective...

Comment: These conditions pretty much limit the regular human to beating the Hulk into submission with bare hands and small firearms, and frankly, are ridicoulus. No sleeping agents, paralysis, no high-tech? That just can't be done.

Answer (score 9):

With the exception of Betty no one would approach the Hulk under your terms, let alone fight him. The Hulk is strength incarnate, he literally has no limit to how strong he can become through rage. It takes considerable plot armor to defeat Hulk and even then it's more of a draw than actual defeat.

To date only 2 individuals have fought and defeated/draw Hulk. The first was the Thing and he had considerable plot armor on his side and the other being Sentry, he used every ounce of power to beat Hulk into changing back into Bruce.

Edit - The Juggernaut has also gone toe to toe with the Hulk and knocked him around. He is the only character that did not need plot armor.

Comment: The Thing and Sentry have superpowers of their own, and the Juggernaut not only wears armor, but is also powered by the Gem of Cyttorak, so none of those count based on the criteria listed out.

Comment: @JoshuaTempleton:   I get that you like the term "plot armor", but three times in three paragraphs is too much!

Comment: Juggernauts armor doesn't really do much, its pretty much all the Gem as it makes him a avatar for the god Cyttorak which bestows godly gifts on him such as invulnerability, similar to Thor. Really his armor is more for style except the helmet which is used to keep mental intruders out.

Comment: @ThePopMachine plot armor is an actual term used to define why a uber powerful character gets beat or survives and unlikely situation etc. it's use in that context was quite valid.

Comment: @Iankill his armor acts as protection against magical attacks and energy attacks as well. Juggernaut is immune to all physical attacks via a force field projected by the stone but is still vulnerable to magical energy and other non concussive forces. the stone can heal any wound he suffers but it takes time.

Comment: @JoshuaTempleton:   Actually, I was just commenting on using it too much.   But now I went and looked it up, and I think you're using it wrong anyhow.   Plot armor (note the ARMOR) is essentially when you know a character won't die, etc, but they are crucial to the plot.  Paraphrasing another forum: Harry Potter can't die in books 1-6 because, no Harry Potter, no Harry Potter franchise.   How you contorted this to explain how a character needs to DEFEAT the Hulk is beyond me.   Plot armor prevents a character from dying, doesn't necessitate they BEAT the Hulk. ...

Comment: ... (contd)   They could get thrashed by the Hulk and still survive to carry on the plot at needed.    "Plot armor" isn't a catch-all for "this happened because that's the plot they wanted".   It means "this character didn't disappear/die because they are too important".   Maybe this is a subtle point.   Why did Picard survive assimilation?   Because plot armor.   But any arbitrary thing to which the answer is, "this didn't happen because otherwise there's no story" isn't plot armor.

Comment: Plot armor is also used among comic fanboys to explain why character who should have had their behind handed to them accomplish what they did despite all odds against them. it's a common argument in my comic group.

Edit- especially among Batman haters they believe it was not for plot armor he would never survive any encounters.

Comment: @JoshuaTempleton:   ***survive***   you said you yourself!   Plot armor is unlikely invulnerability, not just any unlikely outcome

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, the answer is **no**. I don't think there is anything short of cosmic powers than can beat him. As Joshua Templeton noted, during *World War Hulk*, both Juggernaut and Sentry fought him to draw.  Juggernaut is regularly depicted as being *literally* unstoppable, and Sentry has fought and defeated a herald of Galactus, and neither of them could best the Hulk. What chance does a mere mortal have?

There is one (non-canon) instance that I know of where a normal person beat the Hulk: [Punisher Kills the Marvel Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punisher_Kills_the_Marvel_Universe). In a story where the Punisher defeats Wolverine, Ghost Rider, Doctor Doom, and just about every other superhero and villain in the Marvel universe, how does he kill the Hulk? He waits until the Hulk has gone on a rampage and turned back into his unpowered form, and then shoots Bruce Banner.  Even in this one-off story, one of the toughest non-super characters doesn't actually defeat the Hulk.

There may be other instances that I'm not aware of, but I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Deadpool beats him the same way too, except he just lets himself get smashed, and waits until the hulk falls asleep and turns into bruce to regenerate, and kill him.